# itemCount in GridView.builder inside a Consumer

Tags: flutter, gridview, consumer

itemCount seems not updated by the consumer. this causes the GridView scroll not to work.

```
    return Consumer<CollectionData>(
    builder: (context, collectionData, child) => GridView.builder(
        ...
        itemCount: Provider.of<CollectionData>(context).itemsLength,
        
        itemBuilder: ...
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `collectionData` parameter of the `builder`:

```
itemCount: collectionData.itemsLength,
```

Comment: I tried, behaves the same. debugging the collectionData.itemsLength inside the itemBuilder, shows the correct value, but the gridview is not scrolling past the initial value.

Comment: How does your `itemBuilder` looks like?

Comment: `if (index == collectionData.collection.items.length - 4) {
                collectionData.paginate();
              }
              if (collectionData.collection.items.asMap().containsKey(index)) {
                return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
                    },
                    child: NftItem(
                      nft: collectionData.collection.items[index],
                    ));
              }`

Comment: Is `collectionData.collection.items.length` the same as `collectionData.itemsLength`?

Comment: yes, itemsLength I set internally in the CollectionData, they're the same, but neither can make the widget scroll once the change notifier gets more data